# Convert ISO DateTime to UnixTimestamp in sql where clause - DBeaver client, postgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, epoch

I have a column named 'CreatedAt' in postgres (DBeaver client) that is an int8 datatype and holds a unix timestamp value. Example: 1659347651689

I am writing a query that I'd like to input an ISO datet ime in the where clause and have it automatically convert to find the applicable records.

For example:
Normally, I'd write:

```
select * from table1 where CreatedAt = '2022-08-01 09:54:11.000'
```

I can't do that because the CreatedAt column value is 1659347651689.  Is there a way to have it automatically convert and locate the record with that datetime?

I tried this:

```
`select * from table1 where CreatedAt = date("CreatedAt",strtotime('2022-08-01 09:53:27.000'))`
```

but strtotime doesn't exist (guessing because it's a Python command. I tried date, dateadd, but no luck)

Comment: [`EXTRACT(EPOCH ..)`, `to_timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT).

Comment: https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data appears to be in milliseconds, so:

```
select to_timestamp(1659347651689/1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes thank you Jeroen Mostert and a_horse_with_no_name (great userid).  After reading the links here, I got it.

If anyone else is looking, the answer is:

select * from table1 pfs
where timestamp 'epoch' + pfs."CreatedAt" /1000  * interval '1 second' = '2022-08-01 09:53:13.000'